# How to add span to a label using $form->labelEx from Yii?

Tags: yii

I wish to generate the following markup:

```
<label>some label here <span>(optional)</span></label>
```

Is there a way to do this, by using Yii *labelEx* or just *label*?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

**If the attribute is required**

You can set the CHtml static properties like this

```
CHtml::$beforeRequiredLabel = '';
CHtml::$afterRequiredLabel = '<span>(optional)</span>';
```

Yii will generate a tag

```
<label>CHtml::$beforeRequiredLabel.$label.CHtml::$afterRequiredLabel</label>
```

but the static properties will effect all labels generated by $form->labelEx() (@see CHtml::activeLabelEx())

if you don't need, you must set the static properties to default

**If the attribute is not required**

you can set the htmlOptions

```
$form->labelEx($model, $attribute, array('label' => 'your label'))
```

Comment: @Yangmis: Care to explain what attribute required and attribute not required means? Please also note: your second block, seems to generate two labels and that's not the intended result.

Answer (score 3):

It's simple, make use of the Decorator pattern:

```
<?php
// components/CustomCHtml.php

class CustomCHtml extends CHtml
{
    public static function activeLabelEx($model,$attribute,$htmlOptions=array())
    {
        if (isset($htmlOptions['optional']) && $htmlOptions['optional']) {
            if (isset($htmlOptions['label']) && $htmlOptions['label']) {
                $htmlOptions['label'] .= $htmlOptions['optional'];
            } else {
                $htmlOptions['label'] = $htmlOptions['optional'];
            }
        }

        return parent::activeLabelEx($model,$attribute,$htmlOptions);
    }
}
```

use case:

```
<?php echo CustomCHtml::activeLabelEx($model, 'field', array('optional'=>' <span>(optional)</span>')); ?>
```

Comment: really? 10 lines of code to add a span... Decorator patterns... for a span... :)

Comment: This is brilliant! It enables you to create dynamic labels on the fly and still display the 'required' mark. And you can expand the code to include other data in the label. For example: after each label, I display the maximum number of characters the user may enter. Best 10 lines of code I found in a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little hack to make it possible.

```
<?php 
                $username = $form->field($model, 'username')
                ->input('text', ['class' => 'form-control input-lg'])
                ->label(true, 'username', ['class' => 'fa fa-user signin-form-icon']);

                $username->parts['{label}'] = '<span class="fa fa-user signin-form-icon">dwe</span>';

                echo $username;
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `CHtml::$afterRequiredLabel` and/or `CHtml::$beforeRequiredLabel`

```
$initValue = CHtml::$afterRequiredLabel;
CHtml::$afterRequiredLabel = $initValue.'<span>(optional)</span>';
echo $form->labelEx($model, $fname, array('class' => ''));
echo $form->textField($model, $fname, array('class' => ''));
CHtml::$afterRequiredLabel = $initValue;
```

This way the label will be applied only on the specified form field. You actually set the initial value of `CHtml::$afterRequiredLabel` and/or `CHtml::$beforeRequiredLabel` on a temp variable, you overwrite the value that you need, and then reset it to original value.